# How can i use if valueChanges?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

There is a chat section in my app , scrollBottomOnInit() function works but only for the sender.

**Question 1** :
I want to scrollBottomOnInit() function works when valueChanges() How can I fix ?

**Question 2** : when user out this page Does the valueChanges() continue to work?

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { IonContent } from '@ionic/angular';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-group-chat',
  templateUrl: './group-chat.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./group-chat.page.scss'],
})
export class GroupChatPage implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(IonContent, {read: IonContent, static: false}) content: IonContent;
  messages: Observable<any[]>;
  myUid : any
  message :string = ""
  campId : any
  name : any
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,private db : AngularFireDatabase,private NavCtrl : NavController) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap=>{
      this.campId=paramMap.get('campId')
      this.myUid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
      this.db.database.ref("/users/"+this.myUid).once("value",c=>{this.name = c.child("name").val()})
//this.message (receive message)
      this.messages = this.db.list("/forms/"+this.campId+"/chat/").valueChanges();// if valueChanges then call scrollBottomOnInit()
    })
  }
  sendMessage(){
    
    var chatId =this.db.createPushId();
    this.db.object("/forms/"+this.campId+"/chat/"+chatId).update({
      name : this.name,
      message : this.message,
      who:this.myUid
    }).then(a=>this.message="")       
        
     
 this.scrollToBottomOnInit(); // this is work but only for sender  
}
scrollToBottomOnInit() {
  setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.content.scrollToBottom) {
          this.content.scrollToBottom(400);
      }
  }, 500);
}

}
```

**EDIT** :
I used async so do i need unsubscribe ?

**this is my template** :

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>campChat</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row *ngFor="let item of messages | async">
      <ion-col size="9" *ngIf="item.who!==myUid" class="message other-message">
        <span>{{item.message}}</span>
      </ion-col>
  
      <ion-col offset="3" size="9" *ngIf="item.who===myUid" class="message my-message">
        <span>{{item.message}}</span>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
  </ion-content>
  
  <ion-footer >
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input [(ngModel)]="message">
  
        </ion-input>
        <ion-button slot="end" (click)="sendMessage()">
          <ion-icon name="send-outline" slot="icon-only"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-footer>
```

Comment: What is the return type of this: `this.db.list("/forms/"+this.campId+"/chat/").valueChanges()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The valueChanges method from firebase is an observable that return the current values, based on your query, in your realtime database. You will need to subscribe to it to get its content (if it's not already done in the template with the async pipe).
You can add a tap operator to your observable. Each time valueChanges emit a new value, it will execute what's in the [tap operator](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap):

```js
...
this.messages = this.db.list("/forms/"+this.campId+"/chat/")
  .valueChanges()
  .pipe(
    tap(() => scrollToBottomOnInit()) 
  );
...
```

For your second question, when your user leave the page, if you let the subscription open, it will continue to emit values. you'll need to unsubscribe to avoid memory leak.
If you use a pipe async in your template, angular does it for you.
If you subscribe to it in your component, use the ngOnDestroy method to unsubscribe:

```js
messagesSubscription: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
  ...
  this.messagesSubscription = this messages.subscribe();
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.messagesSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
...
```

Comment: I share my template so do i need unsubscribe ?

Comment: @zafer no you don't need to, since your are using a pipe async